# ls *.csv --ignore="*pattern*" returns files which contain "pattern"

Tags: filesystems, directory, files, ls

Why does `ls --ignore` not ignoring the pattern?

Looking at the below example:

```
mkdir books
cd books
touch books_abby.csv
touch books_karen.csv
touch books_david.csv
touch books_tom.csv
```

This creates four files:

```
$ ls
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv  books_tom.csv
```

If however you want to ignore all filename containing "tom" and list them, `books_tom.csv` is still returned:

```
$ ls *.csv --ignore="*tom*"
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv  books_tom.csv
```

The expected outcome is for files containing "tom" to be omitted:

```
$ ls *.csv --ignore="*tom*"
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--ignore` option of `ls` seems to be OK and working, but the problem seems to occur when you mix it with `*.csv` in the same `ls` command.

So, you can get the same result using (since all your files end with .csv):

```
$ ls *.csv --ignore="*tom*"
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv
```

If you have other files extensions that you don't want to show up in the output, you can try:

```
$ ls !(*tom*).csv
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv
```